# Segue to UIViewController without initializing a new object

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am building in iOS 9 with Swift 2.0. I have my starting UIViewController that is my menu screen. It contains the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let id = segue.identifier where id == "GamePlayScene" {
        self.gameVC = segue.destinationViewController as? GameViewController
        self.gameVC!.delegate = self
        if let s = sender as? GKTurnBasedMatch {
            self.gameVC!.match = s
        }
    }
}
```

When segueing to my GameViewController, the following init runs before that prepareForSegue even gets called:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().registerListener(self) // I only want this once
}
```

In storyboard, my GameViewController has a "Menu" button that is connected to the exit widget for the view controller and it unwinds to the Menu as intended. But whenever I perform the segue again, the init gets called again so I now have multiple GameViewControllers. I think this slows my app down since I am using SKScenes. **How do I perform a segue without it creating a new object every time?**

```
func player(player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventForMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {
    if didBecomeActive {
        // This event is what activated the app, so the user wants it right meow
        GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.match = match
        performSegueWithIdentifier("GamePlayScene", sender: match)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store your `GameViewController` in a singleton so that it only needs to be created once. Since the view controller is initialized only once it saves processing time. This is probably a good performance optimization for an app using two view controllers, such as your game, that need to frequently be switched back and forth between the two.

The way to do this is to create a new Swift class and have it accessible as a shared instance where the second view controller is stored in a private property. The second view controller is instantiated if it has not yet been initialized. Further retrievals of the view controller return the stored view controller thereby eliminating the need to initialize the view controller. The operations for creating the view controller, storing it, and returning it are handled by the getter of a publically accessible computed property.

Here is the code for the class:

**Singleton.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    var gameViewController: GameViewController {
        get {
            if self.storedViewController == nil {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                self.storedViewController = 
                     storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as? GameViewController
            }

            return self.storedViewController!
        }
    }

    private var storedViewController: GameViewController?

}
```

To use this, it will be necessary to use the `showViewController` method of showing the game view controller instead of using a segue.

In the first view controller I have:

```
@IBAction func buttonWasPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = Singleton.sharedInstance.gameViewController
    navigationController?.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
}
```

The second controller (GameViewController) **will now only be created once and re-used every time the button is pressed** on the first view controller.

Comment: Will the exit functionality of the GameViewController still work? When I unwind to the menu, does anything get deallocated?

Comment: @dem7w2 My example uses a navigation controller. When the back button is pressed, the view controller does not get deallocated. Using this optimization may require you to change how you are navigating between views. I don't believe it will support using segues in the storyboard. However, it's relatively easy to set up with a navigation controller using `showViewController:sender:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that since there are other screens like Options and Challenges and Solo Mode which needs to see an additional view before moving on to the game view controller. Nevertheless, `showViewController` will most likely do what I need, thank you.

Comment: No problem, @dem7w2. I'm glad that can work for you. Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().registerListener(self) // I only want this once
> ```

The way to cause a line of code to run only once over the lifetime of the app is with `dispatch_once`.